# Personal proxy server software that filters DNS response and protects against DNS rebinding attacks on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, dns, proxy

Thanks to [this question/answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/106947/6103), I now need to find a personal proxy server that filters DNS responses and protects against [DNS rebinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding) attacks.

I'd prefer that it runs on Windows as employers seem to have a real knack for always using that despite my judgment to the contrary.

Can you suggest one?  The one suggested by the poster seems to be a dead project.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting a response here; can you move this to the security stackexchange?

Answer (score 0):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) has various controls you could use for this.

For starters you can set minimum TTL in the DNS resolver, and force caching of results.  This prevents effective use of rebinding over shorter timeframes.

You can also do web policy that will prevent connecting to internal IPs via the proxy, or require host header name matches (if for example your intranet server doesn't do this).

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who are the author of WinGate

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend to go the full way instead of just reacting to this one requirement. The best thing in this direction i ever discovered is RouterOS from Mikrotik. It costs a few bugs but it is really a nice general networking solution.

https://mikrotik.com/download (I am not affiliated with mikrotik or friends, i just use it)